# $.getJSON not worked inside $('# ').click(function()

Tags: django, jquery

am new to jquery.I am doing some ajax using jquery in django.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.getJSON('/jsonserver/', function(json){
    alert("JSON Data: " + json);
    });
```

The above jquery worked for me. When I put the same in click function a button,it calling the url successfully ,But alert doesn't display.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#save').click(function(){          
           $.getJSON('/jsonserver/', function(json){
            alert("JSON Data: " + json);
                });

          });   
    });
<form method ="POST" method =/jqueryserver/ name ="form1" id ="form1">
    <input type= "submit" id = "save" name ="save" value ="Save" />
</form>
```

view.py

```
def jsonserver(request):
    print "...jsonserver..."
    json = simplejson.dumps('hello world!')
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype = 'application/json')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `$("#save")` is a submit button, clicking that button is going to submit the form, and refresh the page.

What you want to do is "hijack" that by preventing the browser's default events from firing.

That can be done like this:

```
$('#save').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.getJSON('/jsonserver/', function(json){
      alert("JSON Data: " + json);
   });
});
```

Comment: This problem is an issue even if the button is not a submit button....and the e.preventDefault solves it...